# Netty 3.4.1-Final Maven availability

Tags: netty

I saw from the Netty commits emails that there's a 3.4.1-Final pending. Any sense for when this will make it to Maven repositories? Thanks! David

Answer (score 0):

Its not out yet... I hope we will be able to cut it tomorrow.